# Forgot to encash dividend Cheque!

Tags: india, dividends, shares

My Mother holds shares in a public limited company [India], which announced it's interim dividend last year.
Accordingly, they sent a cheque to her for her share of dividend, but she forgot to encash it.
Cheque is dated 23rd March, 2016 and is now stale.

So, is there any mean by which she can claim that now?

Answer (score 21):

Write to the registrar of the company. They will arrange a fresh cheque.

If your mother is holding physical shares convert them to demat. Dividend are electronically credited to your account.

Comment: You may need to send the stale check back to the registrar to prove you won't make any other attempt to cash it, but contact them first to find out exactly what you need to do. The contact address should be somewhere on the dividend document. Your mother isn't the first (or the last!) person to be in this situation!